# Draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am setting a dashboard. I want to create some circle shape and allow user to drag and drop them between different cells(I use div here)
I am able to drag and drop image from same folder but unable to do so on created circle shape with text inside

I have tried to read W3schools education material
I think the code error roots from the data set to be transferred but I have no clue what to change

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f05;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #f0f;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div class="circle" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">no.1</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to create two divs to allow the texted circle to be moved between them, however it results in nothing.
Please help

Comment: Run your own code.  It would seem to do as you describe.  Is this not what you need?  Please clarify.

Comment: Tried! But I can't move the circle

Comment: Then it may be an issue with your browser.  You must use a browser which supports this.

Comment: I am using chrome Devtool

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:flex;`

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f05;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #f0f;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div class="circle" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">no.1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! It works much better! May I know if I could align the element from left to right?

Comment: just add     justify-content: flex-end; to the parent div "#div1" and remove margin:0 auto; from class .cricle to align circle to right

Comment: Thank you so much!!